# irreducible representations of $S_n$, $O(n)$, $GL_n$

Tags: representation-theory

I'm trying to understand the relation between some results in representation theory. Let $V_n$ be some n-dimensional vector space.

$\bullet$ Every irreducible representation of $S_n$ occurs in $V_n^{\otimes d}$ for $d$ a natural number;

$\bullet$ Every irreducible representation of $GL_n$ occurs in $V_n^{\otimes r}\otimes V_n^{* \otimes s}$ for $r,s$ natural numbers;

$\bullet$ Every irreducible representation of $O(n)$ occurs in $V_n^{\otimes d}$ for $d$ a natural number;

First of all, how can I proof these results (some intuition or nice references)? And, maybe the proof clarify me, but how can I relate these similar results and conclude something general in the context of representation theory?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest to post **one** question, instead of a list of them.

Comment: I don’t think $V_n$ in these examples is just “some” vector space, it should be a representation of each group.